# Написать тригер в Postgres, который принимает id пользователя (user_id)

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql, триггер

При создании нового пользователя в **Postgres** у меня стоит триггер который автоматически создает ему чат (по типу saved messages в telegram).

У меня также в бд есть таблица **chat_members**, которая хранит участников чатов связью много ко многим пользователей и чатов.

Необходимо написать триггер, который при создании любого чата будет автоматически записывать в таблицу **chat_members** его создателя, но я не знаю как передать id пользователя, так как в таблице **chats** нет такой колонки. Одним из решений является добавление колонки created_by в таблице chat, и запись туда создателя чата, а потом триггер берет этот id и создает запись в таблице chat_members.

Моя схема бд в Supabase:

[image: Supabase db schema]

Сам триггер и функция которая создает чат:

```
create function public.create_user_saved_chat()
returns public.chats as $$
declare
    new_chat public.chats;
begin
    insert into public.chats (type, name) 
    values ('saved', 'Saved chat')
    returning * into new_chat;
    
    return new_chat; 
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

```
create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as $$
begin
    perform public.create_user_saved_chat();

    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create trigger on_auth_user_created
  after insert on auth.users
  for each row execute procedure public.handle_new_user();
```

Comment: Покажите структуру таблицы, на которой висит триггер и код этого триггера, который создает чат

Comment: @SwaD Структуру таблицы (auth.users) создает сам [Supabase](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data) (альтернатива Firebase с Postgres БД). Там очень много метаполей, не вижу смысла добавлять в вопрос.  Код триггера добавил в вопрос.

Comment: В этой таблице есть id пользователя?

Comment: @SwaD Естественно есть.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, что в таблице **auth.users** ID пользователя хранится в поле **user_id**, тогда:

В функции **public.handle_new_user** добавляем переменную и присваиваем ей значение из **NEW.chat_id**(значение поля после вставки записи).

> **NEW** это специальная переменная типа Record. Переменная содержит новую строку базы данных для команд INSERT/UPDATE в триггерах уровня строки. [Более подробно о триггерах в PostgreSQL](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/plpgsql-trigger)

В функцию **create_user_saved_chat** добавляем входящий параметр **iduser**.

При вызове **create_user_saved_chat** из функции **handle_new_user** передаем **user_id**

В функции **create_user_saved_chat** добавляем **insert** нужных нам данных в таблицу **chat_members**, так как нам теперь известно и id нового чата и id пользователя

```
create function public.create_user_saved_chat(iduser integer)
returns public.chats as $$
declare
    new_chat public.chats;
begin
    insert into public.chats (type, name) 
    values ('saved', 'Saved chat')
    returning * into new_chat; -- Тут лежит созданная строка
    
    insert into public.chat_members (chat_id, user_id)
    values (new_chat.id, iduser); -- Сохраняем
    return new_chat; 
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as $$
declare 
  IDUSER INTEGER = NEW.user_id; -- ID созданного пользователя
begin
    perform public.create_user_saved_chat(IDUSER);

    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

Comment: Вы поместили в одну функцию 2 разных логики. Первая - создание чата. вторая - добавление пользователя, который создал чат в таблицу участников чата (chat_members). Да, это скорее всего будет работать, цель моего вопроса - создать два триггера которые в моем случае будут работать по цепочке. Пользователь регистрируется - для него создается чат, далее, поскольку чат создан, срабатывает еще один триггер, который вносит этого пользователя в таблицу chat_members как участника чата. И необходимо откуда-нибудь получить id пользователя для второго триггера.

Comment: Объясняю, почему хочу сделать именно так, допустим, пользователь самостоятельно захочет создать чат -тогда сработает только второй триггер. И не придется дублировать логику по добавлению пользователя в таблицу участников чата.

Comment: @Igor Хотите усложнить себе жизнь и поддержку? Если у вас эта цепочка является одним "бизнес процессом" то зачем его дробить на разные составляющие. Если хочется, то придется в таблице, на которую вы хотите повесить триггер, создавать поле, вида create_user, куда надо будет записать id пользователя. По другому никак, т.к. триггер будет инициировать отдельный поток обработки данных

Comment: спасибо за ответ. То есть лучше объединить две логики в одну или создать дополнительный столбец (create_user как вы сказали) ?

Comment: @Igor Если это разные логики, но имеющий общий функционал, то лучше их разделить, однако за тот или иной участок(добавление/изменение/удаление) должен отвечать один компонент(процедура/функция и т.д.). Так же, для того что бы это работало, инициатор процесса должен передавать все необходимые данные для этого или минимально достаточные, что бы можно было подзапросами вытащить нужную информацию. Т.е. если пользователь создает чат, то надо передать ID пользователя. Если вы логику организуете только на БД, то без поля "ID создателя" не обойтись

Comment: @Igor Ну и вопросы лучше формулировать полностью. Ваш вопрос: *как при создании пользователя прокинуть его ID до нужной таблицы*, а получается, что вопрос должен звучать так: *как достать ID пользователя при добавлении данных в таблицу, если ID пользователя не передается и не хранится в таблице*. Возможно, у вас еще какие то процедуры, которые все таки получают нужные данные, но вы решили это сделать триггерами... Пересмотр архитектуры приложения, частенько, помогает найти нужное решение, да еще и с оптимизацией.